# Unity. Адаптивность игровых объектов под разрешение

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр, ui, unity3d-ui

Есть у меня в двухмерной игре объекты. К примеру, есть некий ассистент, который вылезает из-за экрана и напоминает игроку, что нужно сделать какое-то действие. Есть палитра для раскрашивания. Она тоже является не UI, а игровыми объектами, так как игрок выбирает карандаш и он подлетает к объекту, отрабатывает анимация закрашивания и карандаш возвращается обратно.

Так вот. Возможно вы скажете, что я не прав и это можно как-то делать в GUI (но я не уверен). А возможно подскажет как мне сделать эти объекты адаптивными под разрешение? У палитры есть фон - он должен растягиваться на всю ширину (а лучше и самим объектам давать размер пропорционально ширине/высоте). Ассистент у телефонов вылезает из-за экрана, а вот у планшетов уже вылезает из воздуха.

Не смог Гугл мне помочь в этом. Всегда ссылает на GUI. Буду благодарен любой помощи.

Comment: Позвольте уточнить. Вы хотите сделать адаптивность через скрипт или через возможности редактора?

Comment: На самом деле это не важно. У меня пока в голову приходит очень странный вариант - в методе Start подгонять Position и Scale по полученной ширине/высоте разрешения устройства :) Это звучит тупо, поэтому хотел бы уточнить какие есть ещё варианты.

Comment: А приложение будет поддерживать изменение положения устройства Portrait/Landscape?

Comment: @МихаилИсаев, хочу добавить что объекты с измененным Scale попадают в отдельную категорию сжигания ресурсов, увеличивающую кол-во Draw Calls. Поэтому крайне не стоит их подгонять особенно в больших кол-вах в проекте именно по Scale

Comment: У вас трудности в использовании UI? Я не совсем не понимаю почему используете ради такой цели обьекты

Comment: @AlemkhanUtepkaliev, у UI есть коллизии и триггеры? Как минимум хочется понять это. Есть ли у UI объектов сценарии запуска анимации? Могу ли я добавить UI элемент на сцену по таймеру, проиграть анимацию и при воздействии на этот элемент переключить эту самую анимация?

Comment: По поводу ресурсов - согласен. Но тут вопрос в том, есть ли у меня другие варианты.

Comment: Конечно, всё что описали возможно с UI вопрос в том почему Вы решили что нельзя)

Comment: Вы решили свой вопрос?

Comment: Да, спасибо. Это оказалось проще, чем я думал